# SIMD - _mm256_shuffle_epi32 что за странная функция

Tags: c++, c, simd

Подскажите пожалуйста, что это за "странная" такая функция перемешивания:

> __m256i _mm256_shuffle_epi32 ( __m256i a , const int imm8 )
>
> Описание: Перемешайте 32-битные целые числа в пределах 128-битных
> дорожек, используя элемент управления в imm8 , и сохраните результаты
> в dst .

То есть получается, какая то странная ситуация: у меня 256 битный вектор, который заполнен 8-ю 4-ех байтными значениями, но функция может перемешивает только 4-е 4-ех байтных элемента в нем и только в пределах 128 бит.

И при этом, какой то другой функции, которая может перемешать все 8-емь 4-батныйх значений - нет.

Answer (score 1):

Данная функция перемешивает значения внутри старших 128 бит, и младших по отдельности по маске заданной в imm8. Нашел пример на Rust:

```
let a = _mm256_setr_epi32(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);

let c1 = _mm256_shuffle_epi32(a, 0b00_11_10_01);
let c2 = _mm256_shuffle_epi32(a, 0b01_00_10_11);

let expected1 = _mm256_setr_epi32(1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 6, 7, 4);
let expected2 = _mm256_setr_epi32(3, 2, 0, 1, 7, 6, 4, 5);
```

expected1 - то что должно получится в результате применения маски `0b00_11_10_01`.
(Соответствует `c1`).

expected2 - то что должно получится в результате применения маски `0b01_00_10_11`.
(Соответствует `c2`).

[Ссылка на пример Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/arch/x86/fn._mm256_shuffle_epi32.html)